# typing in TextBox and Empty TextBox on pressing enter

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

i have windows form application with TextBox and i want to type in title (form1) and when i press enter it will delete what i type in title

[image]

Comment: Your image shows no TextBox and you've added no C# code, so it's hard to tell what you're looking for. Stackoverflow is not a coding service. Please share what you tried so far in the post itself

Comment: Also, tell us waht you tried - this starts looking like "I fail learning to program in my course/class, so I try to outsource and maybe if I fake it enough, one day I can make it and get a job". That is not how it works. So, try something and then ask for specific help.

Comment: By the way, "typing in the title" is not possible

Comment: I'm new in this website so I don't know how can i use it or how can i ask so sorry about that and i will try to edit what u told me about it .. thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @OneCricketeer It is not possible with the default design. However, it is possible to remove all decorations and add indeed a TextBox in place of the title.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need some help understanding "form" structure.
To change title of a windows form:

1. Select the form named "Form1"
2. Go to properties
3. Look for "Text" property it should say "Form1"
4. Replace "Form1" with "My title" for example.
   And there you go. :)
   Take a look a this Microsoft tutorial for setting up a simple forms app

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/step-3-set-your-form-properties?view=vs-2019